# How to use ruby 2.7 on my Ruby on Rails applications

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I updating my applications that are running in AWS OpsWorks so I need to use Ruby 2.7, but the newest version showing is 2.6.
Can I force my stack to use 2.7 version?

Answer (score 1):

According to this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-ruby.html

Version 2.7 is not yet available for OpsWorks.